# getTopLevelClasses doesn't contain class info

Tags: java, guava

```
ImmutableSet<ClassPath.ClassInfo> classPaths = 
classPath.getTopLevelClasses("examplepackage");
```

This set doesn't contain any classinfo. 
I know it because

```
for(ClassPath.ClassInfo classInfo : classPaths)
```

is never executed.

I need to get all the classes in a certain package. I spelled the package name right. What can I do?
I also tried with

```
getTopLevelClassesRecursive("examplepackage");
```